# What is the purpose of this? (function ($) { //function code here })(jQuery);

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am debugging someone else's JavaScript code and a majority of the code is wrapped like this:

```
(function ($) {
    //majority of code here...
})(jQuery);
```

What is going on with the `($)` and the `(jQuery)`? I wasn't taught to code like that and haven't seen them. What is their purpose?

As well, there is no `document.ready`, but I assume that is because the code is executed right after it's read by the `();` at the end?

Comment: That code will be executed on document.ready

Comment: @longbkit: Nope, that isn't DOM ready code.

Comment: @longbkit , no , that is not what it means. Please go and read about closure .. or , hell , start to learn javascript.

Comment: @Raynos WHY U NO UNDERSTAND 'THIS MAY BE A NOOB QUESTION'

Comment: @tsdexter [it's simply a function that's being called](https://gist.github.com/1403213)

Comment: Switching from `document.ready` to `(function($) {})(jQuery);` fixed a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8856172/7563449) for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var $ = "some value we don't care about";

 // v=====normal plain old function
(function ($) {
 //        ^=======receives jQuery object as the $ parameter

    //majority of code here, where $ === jQuery...

    $('.myclass').do().crazy().things();


})(jQuery);
 //  ^=======immediately invoked, and passed the jQuery object


 // out here, $ is undisturbed
alert( $ ); // "some value we don't care about"
```

Comment: Okay, so basically the whole point of doing this is so that you can call jQuery with the $() notation inside that function, and outside that function if something else like prototype uses $() notation it doesn't matter?.. So really it just saves you from having to write jQuery() (or some other notation) every time when using no conflict.. makes sense

Comment: Essentially everything, that is in the `majority of code here ...` bit, is isolated from the rest of the code. It exists in separate scope. If you create `var something = 1` there , it does not end up on global `window` scope. The code outside this structure cannot overwrite anything that is inside.

Comment: @tsdexter: Yep, you've got it. The global `jQuery` is referenced by the local `$`, which means the global `$` (if any) can be used for other purposes. In JavaScript, variable scope is created with a function.

Comment: For the record, these are referred to as IIFEs – immediately invoked function expressions. :)

Comment: @davidchambers: Yes, that's a much better description than the still popular "self invoking function" which isn't a proper description of what's happening.

Answer (score 13):

This is useful when you want / need to use [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), and the global name `$` isn't an alias for jQuery. The code you posted lets you use the shorter `$` to mean `jQuery` inside the anonymous function only, without `$` needing to be a global.

Comment: Thanks, although RightSaidFred beat you to it. Much appreciated.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `jQuery.noConflict` which makes jQuery give up the global `$`.

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand on [RightSaidFred's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8305298/22194) answer a little, when I first saw the `()()` syntax I was a bit befuddled, but it made sense once I realised the brackets are being used to define an anonymous function and then call it. e.g:

```
(function (msg){alert(msg)})('hello');
```

... defines a function and then calls it, passing 'hello' as a parameter.

So the example in the question:

```
(function ($) {
    //majority of code here...
})(jQuery);
```

is passing jQuery into an anonymous function and referring to it as $ within the function, a way of guaranteeing that $ will work for jQuery without interfering with anything else.

Comment: For some reason, this explanation clicked a little better with me :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This structure is called JQuery Plugin, purpose of the plugins is to create a framework of any common task/function in your project, same-way you can extend your plugins according to your usage in different page or in same page. that way you can avoid repeating the same code everywhere.

check it out http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: That structure isn't a mere jQuery construct. And while it may be used when creating a plugin, it doesn't need to be. jQuery plugins are created by extending `jQuery.prototype`.