# IE JQuery ready function not working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Apparently many people have run into this problem, but I have yet to be able to find a solution that works.

I have a bit of code which needs to run once the page has loaded, and so I stuck it inside the following block:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Running initialization");
    initialize();
});
function checkDivLoaded() {
    if ( $('#footer').length == 0) $.error( 'not ready' );
}
function initialize() {
    try{
        checkDivLoaded();
        ...more code here
    } catch (err) {
        setTimeout(initialize, 200);
    }
}
```

This works fine in all browsers, with the exception of IE. There, the code does not execute at all.

This code is at the lowest point on the page that I can put it (using the Zend Framework and page-specific ready() functions means that there is a limit to how low on the page it can go). I've checked the includes for the js files, which are all being loaded from a local version, and they all have the form

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
```

Any ideas?

**NOTE**

When I open the debugger in IE, this starts to work correctly.

Comment: What does "..more code here" contains?

Comment: Don't pass a string to `setTimeout`.

Comment: Is your `src` empty, that be causing issues.  I assume you gave it a real URL, right?

Comment: ...more code is a large bit of code, but IE is not getting that far. Adding an alert to $(document).ready() before calling initialize() does not get triggered. @Rocket src is not empty - I was merely illustrating the format of the inclusions, as some people have raised that as a potential issue in IE.

Comment: @Elie: Ok, I was just checking :-P

Comment: @Elie: Check your console, my guess is IE stopped executing JavaScript earlier in the page, because another script had an error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong here, but there are just a few things I'd like to point out.

Before I do that, check IE's JavaScript console, my guess is an earlier script has an error, and that's why this one never gets run.

Instead of `$(document).ready(function(){});`, you can actually just do `$(function(){})`.  it shouldn't make a difference, though.

Also, please don't pass strings to `setTimeout` (they get `eval`'d in the global scope), pass a function.

```
setTimeout(initialize, 200);
```

Also, are you sure you declared `$jquery` (shouldn't it be `$.error`)?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
       initialize();
   });
   function checkDivLoaded() {
       if ($('#footer').length == 0){
          $jquery.error( 'not ready' );
       }
   }
   function initialize() {
       try{
           checkDivLoaded();
           //...more code here
       } catch (err) {
           setTimeout(initialize, 200);
       }
   }
</script>
```

EDIT: If you're using IE8 or lower, it doesn't add `console` unless the debugger is open (I wish whoever thought that was a good idea has been fired).  If one of your includes uses `console.log` it would be `undefined`, thus stopping all script execution.

Try adding this to the top of the page:

```
window.console = window.console || {log:function(){}};
```

It will make a "fake" `console` object, so that `console.log` will be defined.

Comment: I updated setTimeout the way you suggested, and replaced $jquery with $, but it did not work. I added an alert() before the first call to initialize, and it is not being triggered in IE.

Comment: @Elie: Check the console, maybe an earlier script is dying.  There's nothing in this script that would be causing the `ready` event to not trigger.

Comment: @Elie: Do you have `console.log` in your code by chance?  I know IE (I think 8), doesn't add the `console` object unless the debugger is open (stupid, I know, but it's IE).

Comment: No. I have not put any direct logging in the script. I'm wondering if it's actually been fixed for a while, and there's some caching issue going on, or if it's still broken!

Comment: Nope - it's something about the debugger. When I closed a re-opened the entire window, it went back to the problem.

Comment: @Elie: Weird.  Dunno what's going on =(

Comment: @Elie: Can you add that when the debugger is open, the code works to the question.  So, others can see it and help?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6704/discussion-between-elie-and-rocket)

Answer (score 5):

Just had the same problem. Nearly broken my brain trying to figure out what's wrong.

Turned to be very simple - some code that's executed earlier used **console.log(...)**, but it isn't defined in IE unless the dev tools are enabled.

The fix is simple - either remove/comment console.log or add this code to one of your files before the first *console.log* is used:

```
if (typeof console === "undefined"){
    console={};
    console.log = function(){};
}
```

Comment: this is the simplest answer

Answer (score 1):

Using `(function($) {})(jQuery);` fixed the issue for me.

```
(function($) {
  // body code
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your

```
$(document).ready(function...
```

at the bottom of the code. It could be that IE has not parsed the `initialize()` code prior to the ready function being called.

Comment: Function declarations are [hoisted](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-hoisting-explained/) to the top of their enclosing scope.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question - the scripts are as far down the file as I can put them, but because of the framework, they can't actually be at the bottom. However, the scripts are further down the file from any element they affect.

Answer (score 0):

Write below two lines at top of the page.

```
    window.console = window.console || {log:function(){}};
    if (typeof console === "undefined"){
        console={};
        console.log = function(){};
    }
```

This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

don't know where I've found this solution, but this does work for my IE10.

**An example from my project:**

```
var windowOnload = window.onload || function() {
                $('.toInitiate')[0].click();
                 $('a').click(function() {

                        if(this.className.indexOf("collapse") == -1)
                        {
                            $('.active').removeClass('active');
                            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                            var className = $(this).parent().attr('class');
                        }
                    });

            };

            window.onload = function() {
                windowOnload(); 
            };
```

These codes are executed after loading all the html contents.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I Replaced

```
$(document).ready(function...
```

with

```
jQuery(document).ready(function...
```